# excel access tool ADO connection

Tags: excel, ado, vba

For work we use a forecasting tool (excel) with a database behind it (Access). Data is retrieved from access to excel via ADO. Locally this works rather quickly however on the external server (so everybody worldwide has access) this much slower. Especially the retrieving part from access where working in the tool itself and running macros in there works fine. Is there any reason that the ado connection is much slower and are there possibilities to speed this up?

Regards,

Michiel

Comment: I would assume the connection to the server is taking time to return the data you are accessing. To speed it up, either improve the connection, or reduce the amount of data you actually transfer.

Comment: Thanks. I was a bit unexperienced on this point. Finally we placed the tool on a Citrix server which everybody is able to use from his location.